# Email app test on iphone6

Tags: html, css, iphone, email

So I'm doing some newsletter design, and I received a notice that it looks bad on the iphone 6 plus vs iphone 6, but I don't have an iphone 6 plus device, and I don't know how can I test this, do you guys have some tips, or how should I try to test?

//LE
The problem is inside the email app, not the browser

Comment: Litmus and/or Browserstack. Though this isn't really a SO question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Personally I use the Chrome DevTools to see the content from a specific pseudo-device or user agent and that gives me a general idea of how the end result would look like.

However, I would generally strive to do responsive email designs that adapt to whichever device loading the content.

Litmus normally have the most cutting-edge information on Email Design, and [this specific blog post](https://litmus.com/blog/the-responsive-aware-approach-optimized-design-effort-with-great-gains) speaks of the different aspects of responsive email design. I suggest you follow their guidelines and see example content for great results.

Answer (score 0):

In Chrome developer tools you can emulate an iPhone 6 plus device, however, it is just the resolution and user-agent. Regardless, it may depend on browser and e-mail client in the device, if you have this data it will help you more understand the problem...

Comment: inside the email app looks bad, not the browser

Comment: do you know which e-mail client is being used? Also, more information on what exactly looks bad would be helpful, you could provide a screenshot or demo for us to review

Answer (score 0):

[Browserstack](https://www.browserstack.com/screenshots) will allow you to see what your webpage looks like on several device browsers, including an iPhone 6 Plus.

You might need to put your newsletter online somewhere as a standalone HTML page to test what it looks like in the safari browser, since you won't be able to test the email client itself.

Another tool is [Litmus](https://litmus.com/email-testing) which apparently allows email inbox testing too, though I have not been able to test that.

Comment: my problem is in the email app

Comment: Have you been able to test that it definitely looks okay in the browser?